# Erro no map: this.state.filmes.map is not a function. Não estou conseguindo acessar as informações do results. Poderiam me ajudar?

Tags: javascript, html, react

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

export class ListaFilmes extends Component{


    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            filmes: [],
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {


        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/filmes?page=1",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',

            success: function (resposta) { 

                this.setState({filmes: resposta});
                console.log(resposta);




            }.bind(this),
            error: function (data) {

                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>

                {this.state.filmes.map((item) =>
                 <li key={item.results}>{item.results}</li>


                )} 

            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nunhuma [dessas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=map+is+not+a+function+%5Breact%5D) resolve seu problema? Parece que esse é um erro comum no React

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O que ocorre é que no seu state o "filmes" é um array, mas, o retorno de sua API é um objeto. Como você está atribuindo a resposta da API ao state "filmes", você acaba recebendo este erro de "map is not a function", já que "map" se aplica a arrays.

No seu objeto recebido da API, você tem "results", e "results" é um array. Você deve atribuir o valor dele para "filmes".

Sua consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

componentDidMount() {

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/filmes?page=1",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (resposta) { 
        this.setState({filmes: resposta.results});
        console.log(resposta);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function (data) {

        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Coloquei como você pediu!! Deu certo!!! Muito obrigada msm, fiquei um tempão tentando achar o erro!! Me salvouuu